# How to pass Booleans and Views to AsyncTask like a pointer in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've a newbie question about how to pass something like a pointer to AsyncTask class. In C for example I can pass a pointer of a variable or array so original variable or array will be edited inside my function. I need something that work in this way with AsyncTask.
I've 2 booleans(`bool_1` and `bool_2`) and 2 Image IDs(`image_view_id` and `image_drawing_id`) to pass and perform actions on them like this:

```
while(!bool_1)
  sleep;
bool_2 = true;
image_view_id.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_drawing_id);
```

This booleans and IDs are declared in `Main_activity extend Activity` as globals.

Since I have a lot of flags and IDs, I can't create an AsyncTask for every action I need to perform but I can solve passing pointer as in C, how I can do something similar in Android/Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done using `static`

Declare your booleans as `public static`

Now access them from  AsyncTask as

```
MainActivity.boolean_1
```

E.g :

```
Boolean boolean=MainActivity.boolean_1;
MainActivity.boolean_2=boolean
```